# Why do non-native speakers consider "bitch" to mean "prostitute"?

Tags: offensive-language, semantics, learning, non-native-english

Why do so many non-native speakers from very different linguistic backgrounds seem to understand the term *[bitch](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bitch)* as being a synonym for *prostitute*?-- I have never heard a native speaker use the former to refer to ["a person who has sex with someone for money"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/prostitute), and, as a native speaker myself, the word has absolutely no sexual connotations whatsoever. Furthermore, I am familiar with a few other languages, wherein the terms for "a female dog" and "prostitute" are often *not* the same, so it doesn't seem to be some sort of traditional [L1 interference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_transfer).

Comment: I am a non-native English speaker and I've never considered it that way. Also, I have heard native-speakers calling a prostitute a bitch.

Comment: I also have never heard this. In some Romance languages like Spanish, the rough equivalent to calling a woman a "bitch" is to call her a word with the literal meaning of "prostitute" (in Spanish, *[puta](http://www.interglot.com/dictionary/es/en/translate/puta)*). So it seems possible to me that a Spanish speaker might get the idea that "*bitch* is the English word for *puta*," and assume that since the words are used the same way, they have the same literal meaning. But I don't know if that's the situation with the speakers you have heard.

Comment: Indian here. I disagree with your assumption. However, I've seen western movies and rap music where they call prostitutes, and other women under someone's total control, a "bitch".

Comment: *Bitch* is used with maybe 100 different meanings, and different individuals will assign different meanings, based on their background and experience.  I would not assign any great significance to a specific individual's choices for this word.

Comment: Your basic idea is correct: many non-native speakers do confuse the definition. The problem with your premise is in the last sentence. Although many languages have different words for bitch, whore, and prostitute, the usage in the other languages gets blurred. Ex. Spanish: son of a bitch= _hijo de puta,_ where _puta_ translates as whore. Italian: [_figlio de puttana_](http://context.reverso.net/translation/italian-english/puttana), etc. As @Alexander Kosubek commented below, it happens in German, too. If you reword your question with facts, it might get reopened.

Comment: In some languages the _bitch_ is translated `1:1` as _cunt_ - and here is your sexual connection. :)

Answer (score 4):

The **British** definition of *bitch* (from your [link](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bitch)) includes both the following:

> **bitch** noun (UNPLEASANT PERSON)
>   offensive: an unkind or unpleasant woman:
>   *She can be a real bitch.*
>
> **bitch** noun (CONTROLLED PERSON)
>   offensive slang: someone who will do everything you tell them to do because you have complete control over them

Those meanings are **not** included in the corresponding **American** definition, so I assume that it is not used in those ways in American English.

I have often heard (on TV) a prostitute being called a *bitch*, but have always understood that to be a comment on the person's character, and not a synonym for *prostitute*. However, it is easy to understand that a non-native speaker might assume the two words to be synonyms.

Comment: I think the last paragraph hits the mark. A pimp's bitches are his bitches in the sense of the second definition you gave (not necessarily in the sense of the  first one). But it gets across to the uninformed recipient as meaning "prostitute" in general. That's at least my experience from German language dubbings. If "Bitch" (properly capitalized in German) is left untranslated, it lends itself to being misunderstood in this way. And as German imo lacks a proper translation for the word, it usually will be left untranslated.

Comment: We Americans certainly have used it for *"unpleasant woman"* for many decades; I don't understand why your dictionary didn't include that definition. [American dictionaries](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bitch) do. But I don't think we used it for *"controlled person"* before the transplanted Englishman Neil Gaiman said *"George R R Martin is not your bitch."*

Comment: @PeterShor, you've never heard e.g. *he's such a little bitch* or *you're my bitch now*?-- I've heard it used this way since the '90s...

Comment: @errantlinguist: well ... I understood what Neil Gaiman meant, so maybe I had heard it before then. But certainly not often.

Answer (score 2):

I would wager it's because a lot of languages lack an accurate translation for "bitch". I know French, Spanish and Portuguese don't.
As is the case with those languages, most insults to women are different ways of saying "whore", "slut", or, simply, "prostitute".
"Bitch" is actually a very specific concept, if you think about it, and most people wouldn't be able to give an exact definition of what a "bitch" is.
This, of course, is a nightmare for translators, who figure it's fine as long as the audience it's being translated to knows it's meant as an insult.

EDIT: grammar

Comment: Actually, Portuguese (at least European Portuguese) has the word 'cabra' (literally 'she-goat') which is the equivalent to 'bitch'.

Comment: In Spanish, we actually have the word "perra", which means both female dog and unpleasant / mean woman. However, for some reason, we tend to translate bitch as "puta" (whore). Maybe it's because "son of a bitch" is usually tanslated as "hijo de puta".